# Error while inserting record: Column name or number of supplied values do not match table definition

Tags: c#, sql, .net, winforms

Im trying to insert data into my Sql Database but I get the following message:

"Column name or number of supplied values do not match column definition"

Here is the code snippet i wrote for the task:

```
 string sql = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[user_table] VALUES('" + NameOfUser + "," + username + "," + userPIN + "," + category + "," + BeginTimePicker.Text + "," + EndTimePicker.Text + "',@img)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

            conn.Open();    //open connection to database
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@img", img));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  //used with insert, update, delete
            conn.Close();
```

My database table looks like this:
[user_table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bl0Wl.png)

Any idea what might be going wrong? I'm stuck on this for quite some time. Help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What are the columns ijn the table user_table?

Comment: [Bobby Tables](http://www.bobby-tables.com) will be joining the party.

Comment: @Steve I have uploaded a screenshot of the table with the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to put single quotes around every insert value? Right now your SQL looks like:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('value, value2, value3')
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('value', 'value2', 'value3')
```

In other words, change instance of "," in your code to "','"

Comment: I wrote an insert query in exactly the same way in another application and there it worked fine, so I guess the issue is not about that

Answer (score 0):

You must give table fields because of you didn't use userid column in values. Also you are making mistake while preparing insert query, please check prepared sql variable and check it on db management tool.

Comment: userid is set as auto increment in sql server so there is no need to specify it in insert query I guess. Please correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: If you don't insert all columns, you must specify columns. Example: INSERT INTO [dbo].[user_table] (NameOfUser,user_name) VALUES('name','nick')

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory, but the fix is not straightforward: you need to do two things:

- It is always a good idea to specify the list of columns into which you are inserting data. Otherwise your code is going to break when the table definition changes
- It is absolutely not acceptable to build query values into the query string. You need to use parameterized queries.

With these two things out of the way, your insert is going to work.

Comment: When I specify column list, I get this:
There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

I have verified time and again that I provide values for all columns (except userid) as it is set to auto increment in sql.

Comment: @SohaibFurqan you need to list only the columns for which you provide values.

Comment: Yes I know. I'm doing exactly that but still stuck! @dasblinkenlight

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand; the code snippet that I see your using, doesn't marry up with your Database schema is.

You are trying to insert no values into the other columns in the rows.
That would be fine if your Database allowed Nulls. So you might want to revise this. A good trick would be on a piece of paper to write out the column names and have one colour for columns that don't allow nulls while the columns that require values are a different colour. This would help you get your head around it.

I had similar problems myself and it got very confusing with inserting into tables. My solution was Stored procedures. These reduced the complexity of my strings to a standard String. This made it much easier to follow and reduced my errors dramatically. It also allows you test the SQL code out to make sure it is doing what you want it to do before you can proceed and use a different language to implement.

Point of note, I would never use sql where you have it as the string name. It's too close to the Reserved word and though you are doing a small program; when you scale it up, you could get caught up down the line. Try this.

```
String sqlInsertString = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[user_table] VALUES('" + NameOfUser + "," + username + "," + userPIN + "," + category + "," + BeginTimePicker.Text + "," + EndTimePicker.Text + "',@img)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlInsertString, conn);
```

It makes it much easier to follow.

It is easy to knock someone, but I believe that if there is a poor question, pause and help the other person out with how to structure a question,

**Just a quick edit**

If the ID is set to auto increment, no problems there. I would personally never allow nulls in my primary key.

In relation to the rest of your table check your test data to see if you have a value that can be optional, then that of course should be allow null.

Comment: userid is set as auto increment in sql server so there is no need to specify it in insert query I guess. Other than that I believe I'm giving a value to be inserted for every column. Please correct me if I'm wrong?